# Regular expression to cherry pick a multiline component of a paragraph sitting between tags (Not html)

Tags: regex, tags

In the following I need a Regexpr to capture the part between the `<tagstart></tagstart>`

Please note this is **not** html.

```
* real time results: shows results as you type 
* code hinting: roll over your expression to see info on specific elements 
* detailed results: roll over a match to see details & view group info below 
* built in regex guide: doub<tagstart>le click entries to insert them into your expression 
* online & desktop: regexr.com or download the desktop version for Mac, Windows, or Linux 
* save your expressions: My Saved expr</tagstart>essions are saved locally 
* search Community expressions and add your own
```

Thanks

Comment: The fact that it is not HTML is less relevant than the answer to the question "Can these tags be nested?".

Comment: No they can't. Sorry I just didn't want a bunch of people posting links to that question about not reg-exing html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: As @Kobi correctly points out in the comments, the much simpler version of the original post below is of course:

```
<(tagstart)>(.*?)</\1>
```

Since the original version also works and all the other statements remain true, I'll leave it as it is.

---

If (*and only if*) the tags cannot be nested:

```
<(tagstart)>((?:(?!</\1>).)*)</\1>
```

Explanation:

```
<(tagstart)>      # matches "<tagstart>" and stores "tagstart" in group 1
(                 # begin group 2
  (?:             #   begin non-capturing group
    (?!           #     begin negative look-ahead (... not followed by)
      </\1>       #       a closing tag with the same name as group 1
    )             #     end negative look-ahead
    .             #     if ok, match the next character
  )*              #   end non-capturing group, repeat
)                 # end group 2 (stores everything between the tags)
</\1>             # a closing tag with the same name as group 1
```

The regex needs to be applied in "single line" mode (sometimes called "dotall" mode). Either that or you substitute the `.` for `[\s\S]`.

To generically match text between *any* two equally named tags, use `<(\w+)>` instead of `<(tagstart)>`.

Depending on your regex flavor, some things may work differently, like `$1` instead of `\1` for back-references, or meta-characters that need additional escaping.

See a [Rubular demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/ulh6rDR0hG).

Comment: Do you really need the lookahead here? Wouldn't a lazy match of `.*?` behave exactly the same?

Comment: @Kobi: Hm, you are right. Looks like I was thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this regexp: `(\<tagstart\>)(.+)(\<\/tagstart\>)/s` would help you? The second match would be what you are searching for. See [demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/lhubVUQFf5) for details.

Comment: You forgot to add `/m` (i.e. multiline) option at the end

Comment: @shybovycha: also in the demo for completeness ;)

Comment: @digEmAll, jeez... i'm making so many mistakes... seems that night was a bit hard for me =) thanks a lot! =)

Comment: In most regex engines (except Ruby), the `m` modifier will only let `^` and `$` match the start and beginning of lines respectively: it does not let the `.` match line breaks. For `.` to match '\r' and `\n`, you need to enable the `s` (DOT-ALL) flag: `/.../s`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

undef $/;

$_ = <>;

m|<(.*?)>(.*)</\1>|s;

print $2;
```

If you really need just `<tagstart>`, replace the bits like `<(.*?)>` with `<tagstart>` and similar for closing. The `undef $/` bit lets you slurp in a lot with a single read, and the `$2` selects the second match group. The `s` and the end of the regex asks for `.` to match even new-line characters.